# Difference between "NG" and "QB" domain IDs

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

New developer here on the IPP platform. I'm trying to understand the difference between the NG and QB domain IDs, so please correct any mistakes in my assumptions below:

- Records created in Quickbooks Desktop only have "QB" domain id.
- Records created via the API have both a "QB" and "NG" domain id. The default id is "NG" if idDomain attribute is ignored.
- If the record is created via the API, the "QB" domain id is in the ExternalKey tag.

Do I have it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Records created in the cloud (via the API) have an NG domain, which is basically their unsyncronized primary key.

Once they get synced to QuickBooks desktop, they then get a QB domain ID value as well (the QB ID is the syncronized primary key from within QuickBooks).

You should be able to refer to any record by either the NG or QB ID.

What you indicated in your above post sounds correct.